# Simple JavaScript rng

Tags: javascript, random

I just started to learn JavaScript today, and this very simple problem is giving me trouble. This is just part of a larger segment of code, but I isolated it in an attempt to fix it. Here it is:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write(blarg());
function blarg()
{
return (Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-2))+1))
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

All i'm trying to do with this is generate a random number between 1 and 10, and then print that number. It fails and gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token {. This seems like a very simple question, and I'm feeling very dumb...

Comment: You forgot `()` - `function blarg(){....}` - Also, you forgot to `return`

Comment: Did you notice an extra `)` at the end ?

Comment: yeah, thanks! The main problem ended up being a missing semi-colon after "return (Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-2))+1)" Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your blarg function definition.

The syntax of declaring a function should be

```
function name() {
    // function code here
}
```

Complete example:

```
document.write(blarg());

//function blarg{(Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-2))+1))}

function blarg() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 2) + 1);
}
```

Please note your function must return a value to document.write() so that the random number can be displayed.

Comment: thanks so much! I have always taken Java's strong type nature for granted. It has made me soft and blind to the simplest of mistakes in JavaScript... All I forgot was semi-colon...